# Activereports (under VB6) issue

Tags: vb6, activereports

I have to modify an old VB6 program that uses ActiveReports 2.0 at work and I am having some problems (BTW I have never used this program before and only have a basic knowledge of VB6)...

I have to make some text boxes biggers which is pretty easy to do but as soon as I move them a whole section of text (and not simply the content of that text box) disappear.

I have noticed that it was in some sort of section (sorry, I don't know how they call that) which englobed those text boxes so I made  it bigger and that made no difference.

What could be causing this?

Thank you!

Nick

Comment: try commenting out the code to get rid of the 122 blank pages and run it again. If the blank pages stops add one line back at a time to determine which part of the code is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the TextBox is inside a UserControl. A UserControl is created by a developer, and is basically one control with any number of other controls in it. You can check to see if there are any User Controls in your project in the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R).

One way to know exactly what class the control belongs to is to open your form in design mode (Shift+F7), click on the control, and look at the Properties window (F4). The drop-down list should show the currently selected control's class name in bold, then the name of the object.

What is the control's class? If it is anything other than TextBox, then this would explain the unexpected behavior you experienced.

Comment: Knight, I am not exactly clear on what is going on.  When you increase the size of the control, is it overlapping or getting overlapped by another control.  In activereports, the controls will reside in a section, such as a detail, groupheader or a pageheader section.  Can you put a backcolor on that control and run and see if that helps you investigate what is going on.  If possible, please email the report/project to powersupport@grapecity.com and cc me rajnish.sinha@grapecity.com.  I will find out what is going on and get back.

Comment: OK, I checked the structure AND removed any unnecessary possible overlap between each of the items and that didn't change anything... When I started playing more with the form I realized that the size of one of the textbox was programmatically changed so I removed that resize and everything started working... I am left with one last problem though... Even though the "print preview" suggest that I only have 1 page to print everytime I "print" it I end up with 1 page with date and 122 empty pages...

Comment: I am trying to track down that problem now... Thank you guys for the help! Maybe my page is too wide but it would have to be insanely large to cause 122 blank pages...

Comment: OK, it turns out that for some unknown reason the PrintWidth had changed to an incredibly big number (I can only assume this happened when I was copying and resizing the objects), once I changed that back to what it was supposed to be everything went back to normal... Thank you very much for your help guys!